# Issues when building FlutterFlow app with Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, xcode, flutterflow

I have an app from FlutterFlow.

When building on my mac, the app can run on android emulator, however when I try to run the app on iOS emulator I get an error from Xcode:

> Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Using bridging headers with module
> interfaces is unsupported
>
> Uncategorized (Xcode): Command SwiftDriver emitted errors but did not
> return a nonzero exit code to indicate failure
>
> Error (Xcode): no such module '__ObjC'
> /Users/rene.alas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-gmrgdwscnnmvmicqqjbydbrmmixp/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Runner.swiftinterface:13:18
>
> Error (Xcode): failed to verify module interface of 'Runner' due to
> the errors above; the textual interface may be broken by project
> issues or a compiler bug
> /Users/rene.alas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-gmrgdwscnnmvmicqqjbydbrmmixp/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Runner.swiftinterface:0:0
>
> Could not build the application for the simulator. Error launching
> application on iPhone 15.

I tried to check this error on the web an many sources:

**Go to the ios/ folder**

```
cd ios
```

**Update Cocoapods**

```
sudo gem update cocoapods
```

**If the above doesn't work, try installing it through homebrew**

```
brew install cocoapods
```

**Make sure cocoapods updated to 1.13.0 or newer version (if available)**

```
pod --version
```

**Delete the build cache**

```
flutter clean
```

**Delete Podfile.lock**

```
rm Podfile.lock
```

**Delete the Pods/ folder as well**

```
rm -rf Pods/
```

**Install the Flutter package dependencies**

```
flutter pub get
```

**Install the iOS pod dependencies**

```
pod install
```

**Update your local pods**

```
pod update
```

I also tried other options like, deleting the iOS folder from the Flutter project and then running a

```
flutter create .
```

But still getting the same error.

Unfortunately don't know any Swift to Trouble shoot the message inside xcode.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If someone has the same problem I manage to solve it by going to Xcode and doing this:

1. Click Runner
2. Click Build Settings
3. Select All
4. Search for Dist
5. In Build Options you will see: **Build Libraries for Distribution**
6. Change this from Yes to No.